# JBoss 5.1.0 GA servlet API version

Tags: servlets, jboss5.x

Does anyone know what servlet api version is jboss 5.1.0 GA runnning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Servlet 2.5

See [version matrix](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS).